Size Restriction for SAML AuthnRequest ID
I'm working with SAML authentication and I'm curious about the size restriction for the ID attribute in the AuthnRequest element. In my setup, the ID attribute seems to be quite long. Is there a specific size limit I should be aware of ?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:AuthnRequest
    xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://test.com/portal/samlsso" Destination="https://dev.com/app/sso/saml" ForceAuthn="false" 
    ID="_1d598e4f2e8cc7238f98979349c7d58e28a96e6c59637a2as60nk123487_85d5a88c24a15c5b5ed36cc400887683" IssueInstant="2024-03-29T11:15:17.058Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" ProviderName="portal" Version="2.0">
    <saml2:Issuer
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://test.com/portal
    </saml2:Issuer>
    <saml2p:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified"/>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>

I referred to this documentation (section 1.3.4). It seems, it is talking about 160 bits of randomness and not about size restriction. Is my interpretation of this correct ?
Any insights to relevant specifications would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

So there literally isn't an answer to your question, other than don't worry about it, except to the extent that it is more or less globally unique as the article describes. the SAML2 XML schema has the ID field listed as type ID, which maps to the w3c xs:ID type, which is based off the w3c xs:string type. Strings can have restrictions like minLength and maxLenght, but the relevant XSD's don't appear to implement any of them.
